# splitting JSON array element html value using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

This is my jquery function the argument passed is php json_encoded data,

```
   function html_modify(html) {
         var str=JSON.stringify(html);
         var arr=$.parseJSON(str);

         var tot='';
         $.each(arr,function(i,val){

            if(i=='options') {
               alert(val);
            }
         });

    }

  html_modify(<?php echo $encode ?>);
```

The value I will get on alert that is alert(val) will be,

```
       <span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 12pt;"><img style="vertical-align:middle" width=83 height=44 src="image045.gif"></span><span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 12pt;"><img style="vertical-align:middle" width=48 height=44 src="image046.gif"></span><span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 12pt;"><img style="vertical-align:middle" width=48 height=44 src="image047.gif"></span><span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 12pt;"><img style="vertical-align:middle" width=83 height=44 src="image048.gif"></span>
```

I am trying  to remove all the "**spans**" present in the result above and keep only "**image**" tags further. But currently have no clue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the HTML with JQuery but first you should wrap it in a DIV element so that JQuery will be able to iterate over the child elements properly:

```
var div = $("<div/>").append(val);//create a JQuery object for searching
var result = $("<div/>");//build our result JQuery object
```

Then you can loop each span:

```
//loop each span element
div.find("span").each(function(){
    var img = $(this).find("img");//find the img element for the span
    result.append(img);//append the img element to the result object
});
```

and get your final HTML result:

```
var finalHtml = result.html();//convert the result to html string
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xc3mN/)

Comment: Really sorry for not looking into your to the point answer, however i was initially confused with <div/> tag as I have not used it before let me check it thanks.sorry again.

Comment: @echoLearner_php: Just ask if you are unsure about anything, and don't get me wrong as Jai's answer using `unwrap` is a much simpler solution so you can still use that. The `<div/>` used here just creates a parent dummy element that we can search, and also call `html()` on to get the contents. It is just there for the process, it gets discarded when we are finished anyway

Comment: thanks it was working,but if wanted to include each image within a radio button how would I do that?

Comment: when i am trying  to add var radio="<input type='radio' name='choice' value='"+tot+"'>"+img+"</input>"; instead of var img i am getting output like "<input name="choice" value="1" type="radio">[object Object]". is there a way?

Comment: `var radio = $("<input type='radio' name='choice' value='"+tot+"'/>"); radio.append(img); result.append(radio);`

Comment: sorry to bother you, I get radio buttons but nothing between them like "<input type='radio' value='1'><input type='radio' value='2'>" if I use the above trick.

Comment: @echoLearner_php: No idea why it's not working, might be something to do with invalid HTML. [Here is a work around though](http://jsfiddle.net/9U9L3/)

Comment: Thanks Musefan, you are really great :) I learned from you that I should write comments to every code that I write for proper readability.Have a nice day ahead :)

Answer (score 3):

*I am trying to remove all the "spans" present in the result above and keep only "image" tags further.*

So for this you have to find image in val and `.unwrap()` it:

```
if(i=='options') {
   var elem = $(val).find('img').unwrap();
   alert(elem);
}
```

#### [A small demo to you.](http://jsfiddle.net/w6YuV/)

Comment: oh you have to do `val.find().unwrap()` its updated now.

Comment: "TypeError: val.find is not a function" is the result i got.

Comment: make it a jquery object then. `$(val)`. yes this should work now.

Comment: I am getting alert as [object Object] if I use $(val). thanks anyway.

Comment: yes, in console it is printing the object,but what i am getting is object, is there any way to turn it into html like "<img src='image1.jpg'> </img>" so that i can append a "<input type='radio'>" and prepend "</input>" to the images.thanks

Comment: @echoLearner_php: Perhaps you would do well to pay attention to other answers too... then you would know how to fix Jai's code